# Optimization callbacks in MeteorJS

Tags: node.js, meteor

I dont know how to ask my question correctly, but for example I have some structure like this

```
get_data:function(){
    this.unblock();
    request("example.com", Meteor.bindEnvironment(function(error, response, body) {
      if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        $ = Cheerio.load(body);// get HTML of example.com
        $(".someclass").each(function() {
          if (!somedata_doesnt_exist_in_Mongo) {
           request(nexturl, Meteor.bindEnvironment(function(error, response, body)
           //... logic
          }));
        }
      });
    }
  }))
}
```

Main idea is that I get data from many sites like agregator and have a lot of methods like this. And it'a a lot of time. So I have 2 questions

1 - for Meteor guys. When I use `this.unblock()` this ensures that my method will work without taking time with customers, like work in other thread ?

2 - How can I optimaze code stucture like above ?

Sorry if it's not in StackOverflow format but 
I am waiting for any help !

Answer (score 0):

1. `this.unblock` is relevant only to each client individually. It
   allows subsequent method calls from client **A** to run without
   having the previous method calls from that client **A** to finish.
   It is like working in a new thread asynchronously in the sense that
   the previous method calls are not blocking for client **A** for this
   function using `this.unblock`. If you have client **B**, his/her
   method invocation wouldn't be blocking **A**'s regardless of whether
   you use `this.unblock`.
2. I recommend using `this.unblock` whenever you are sure subsequent method calls will not rely on the result of the function you use `this.unblock` in. Sending out emails is the most common example. Subsequent method calls will not need the emails to finish sending before doing its job. For your example, I **think** it should be good to use `this.unblock`, but of course it depends on what you plan to do with the results following the execution of code after `this.unblock`.

Comment: A lot of new ,great! Hey maybe we can talk in any chat about meteor, because I have questions but I cant find answers, what do you think ?